# Session is not timing out in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, session-timeout

I'm developing an ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms application where I would like the session to timeout after a certain period of time. After which, if the user tries to do anything, the application should redirect them to a page stating that the session has timed out and that they will need to start over. Pretty standard stuff, as far as I know.

However, I can't seem to make the session timeout to test this functionality, either running from Visual Studio or from IIS. Here's my session state settings in web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer"
              allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
              sqlConnectionString="<ConnectionString>"
              cookieless="false"
              timeout="1" />
```

Here's how I'm testing for session timeout:

```
public bool IsSessionTimeout
{
    get
    {
        // If the session says its a new session, but a cookie exists, then the session has timed out.
        if (Context.Session != null && Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            string cookie = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie) && cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that `Session.IsNewSession` always returns `false`, which makes sense, because the Session_End method never gets called in my Global.asax.cs. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe Session_End is only called for in process sessions.  Check the Session ID to see if you get a new ID generated after the time expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up implementing.

In Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session[SessionKeys.SessionStart] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

In my pages' base class:

```
public bool IsSessionTimeout
{
    get
    {
        DateTime? sessionStart = Session[SessionKeys.SessionStart] as DateTime?;
        bool isTimeout = false;

        if (!sessionStart.HasValue)
        {
            // If sessionStart doesn't have a value, the session has been cleared, 
            // so assume a timeout has occurred.            
            isTimeout = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, check the elapsed time.
            TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - sessionStart.Value;
            isTimeout = elapsed.TotalMinutes > Session.Timeout;
        }

        Session[SessionKeys.SessionStart] = DateTime.Now;
        return isTimeout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this:

```
        if (Session["myUser"] != null)
            myUser = (User)Session["myUser"];
        else
            myUser = null;

        //User must be logged in, if not redirect to the login page - unless we are already running the login page.
        if ((myUser == null) && (Request.Url.AbsolutePath != "/Login.aspx"))
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?Mode=Timeout", true);
```

in the page_init of my master page for one of my sites. You could adapt it pretty easily for what you want. Basically, check for something that should exist in session, and if it is not there, your session has timed-out and you can take appropriate action.

In my case, they are redirected to the login page. In your case, whenever they start what your 'process' is, you set a session variable. On every page request, see if that item still exists in the session.

Comment: When I saw your answer, I thought that it would solve my problem, but for some reason, my session objects still exist after the timeout period has elapsed. I think that the SQL Server may not be set up properly, but unfortunately, I don't have much control over that. What I ended up implementing combines your answer with a manual check of the elapsed time.